# How do i reference the value of a control in a rowsource query?

Tags: ms-access

Im trying to write a query that will pull the value of the selected item in a combobox to use in a WHERE clause.

For example, the user selects "Jeff" out the combobox that is named cboNames. The bound value is 1 (the primary key). I'm trying to create the query:

```
select * from tbleEmployees where empID = cboNames.Value
```

obviously this doesn't work. Get what I'm trying to do?

How do i place the control value into the query??

Comment: In what context do you want to use the SQL SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from tbleEmployees where empID = [Forms]![YourForm]![cboNames]
```

Comment: I would almost never hardwire a reference to a form control like this, but it really depends on the context (about which we've been provided no information).